# US Immigrant visa, but left without getting Re-enty Permit

Tags: usa

I am an Indian and I got a family-based immigrant visa. We reached the USA on 28th May 2015. At that time I was working in Bahrain and I didn't resign from the job and my daughter was studying in India so we both left the USA on June 25th without getting a Re-entry Permit. Now I am in Bahrain and my daughter is in India. How long I can stay in Bahrain or when we can enter USA without any problem.

Comment: Hi Harshan. Can you edit your question a bit and try to fix the grammar? Your question is very hard to read at the moment, so that we cannot answer.In particular, (1) what do you mean by "we reached us"? (2) From where will you leave to the 25th of June to where? (3) Your sentence starting with "now" seems to discuss the same situation that you mentioned beforehand (you in bahrain, daugther in india). What has changed? (4) What is your question? How long your visa for Bahrain is valid, or when you have to enter the US by the latest in order for the US border officer to be fine with your entry?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're now a green card holder (not entirely clear from your... question?), you can stay outside of the US for a period of up to 1 year *without* the re-entry permit.

However, you'll need a good explanation for your immediate and prolong stay outside of the country. And no, "I have a job in Bahrain" won't do it. You're supposed to **move** your life to the US once you got your green card, or it will be canceled.